# Are server 500 errors a security issue?

Tags: java, security, gwt

I've found that it's possible to cause 500 errors on a server using curl and a faked GWT-Permutation with a POST payload. The payload is generating a java.lang.Exception on an Apache server.

Does this open up a security issue? Should I report it to Google's GWT support?

To clarify the question: Would a significant number of server errors be a concern as a denial of service. I.e. could they exhaust server resources. (Sorry, if this is too hypothetical).

```
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected type 'int' but received a non-numerical value: 
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.getNumberFormatException(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:999)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readInt(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:537)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readString(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:582)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.prepareToRead(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:488)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:240)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:206)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Thanks!
Dave

Comment: If your server is sending back a full stack trace on 500 errors, you should turn that off - that is a configurable feature within your servlet container.

Comment: That stacktrace is from the GWT RPC Server running in Tomcat, not Apache HTTPD.  The problem here is the GWT RPC server isn't being defensive enough about checking its input. If it were correctly written it would catch the error and return an error message about "invalid input" (with a 500 response code) but not a raw stack trace.

Comment: Printing a stack trace is not in and of itself a bad thing - if this is to a log file, it is a good thing, if it is to the html page for a developer it is a good thing, but printing *any* stack trace in production is probably a bad thing. The servlet doPost method is permitted to throw exceptions (else there would be a blanket try/catch at the HttpServlet.service level), it is up to the servlet context or container to stop it from being printed (see the `<error-page>` tag in your web.xml, among other options).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Adam, I've reported it as a bug. I was worried about security implications. The output is going to a log file, not the browser. Omitting the faked GWT-Permutation will generate a SecurityException: Blocked request without GWT permutation header (XSRF attack?)
Showing they are doing some checking--but I agree, not enough.

Comment: Appreciate your comments, @ColinAlworth. I've edited my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously a stack trace is information disclosure.

Beyond that, I believe that a user should -never- see a 500 series error because - what is the user supposed to do about it?

Additionally, from a pentesting and remediation perspective - a 500 error could mean that any number of vulnerabilities exist, or none at all. How do we know?

It also makes it difficult to test the risk of a specific vulnerability. Using a recent example such as the now infamous Log4j vulnerabvility - if I send the ${jndi} payload and I get a 500 error - is it because the payload succeeded or is it entirely unrelated?

IMO all teams need to handle all exceptions, no excuses.

Answer (score 7):

There are two security issues which come to mind.

1) Leaking information about your system.  If a stack trace makes it back to the client side, then you can end up leaking information which could help an attacker build a more effective attack.  You've mentioned that this stack trace is only in your logs, so this point is not an issue.

2) Denial of service.  This is an issue if an attack causes you to leak resources or if it makes the server side do far more processing per request than must be done on the client side.

In your case, if this particular exception causes a connection to be leaked (ie. not properly closed), then you have a DoS attack.  If this attack causes your server to do heavy processing, you also have a DoS attack.  However it looks like neither is probably the case.  It looks like a `NumberFormatException` just kills the request while the server is parsing it.  This is probably less expensive computationally than responding to a well formed request.

From the perspective of adhering to the HTTP spec, there exists a decent argument that the server should return a HTTP 400 Bad Request instead of a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error since the error was the result of a malformed request parameter, however that does stretch into the realm of the pedantic.